# c++ how to disable vector iterate from sorting content?

Tags: c++, winapi, vector

I am in the process of creating a GUI.  In this GUI, I use a listbox.  And in this listbox, I wish to display a list of TCHAR(string) to allow the user to select one element within the listbox. I have a specific order of TCHAR and must be displayed to the user in that sequence.  When upon verifying found that the content is sorted.  I do not want the content sorted. Guidance is appreciated.

Code to initialize the vector:

```
std::vector<const TCHAR*> tstmd = { L"ONE", L"TWO", L"THREE" };
```

Code to access the content of the vector using iterate method:

```
void FillListBox(HWND hwndList, std::vector<const TCHAR *> &vtr)
{

    for (std::vector<const TCHAR*>::iterator it = vtr.begin(); it != vtr.end(); ++it) {

        SendMessage(hwndList, LB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)*it);

    }
```

Here is how I create a listbox:

```
        hwndList = CreateWindow(
            TEXT("listbox"), 
            NULL,
            WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | LBS_STANDARD,
            cxChar * COL_LIST, 
            cyChar,
            cxChar * 16 + GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXVSCROLL),
            cyChar * 3,
            hwnd, 
            (HMENU)ID_LIST,
            (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_HINSTANCE),
            NULL);
```

Comment: I know it is unrelated, but why dont you use the `range for` loop of C++ instead of `for (std::vector<const TCHAR*>::iterator it = vtr.begin(); it != vtr.end(); ++it)`?

Comment: Create the listbox _without_ the `LBS_SORT` style bit set.  You can usually do this in your resource editor (are you using Visual Studio?).

Comment: Not related to the sort issue, but consider using `std::basic_string<TCHAR>` instead of `const TCHAR*`, or better `std::wstring` since you are clearly dealing with Unicode strings only.

Comment: Careful with `TCHAR` here. `L"ONE"` suggests you're expecting wide characters, so the use of `TCHAR` can be a nasty surprise to anyone who compiles without the unicode flag set. Replacing the `L` with the `TEXT` macro should help  here.

Comment: @user4581301 yup, if the project is configured without Unicode enabled, assigning `L"ONE"` to a `const TCHAR*` won't even compile. Use the [`TEXT()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/nf-winnt-text) macro to wrap literals assigned to `TCHAR` variables, eg: `std::vector<const TCHAR*> tstmd = { TEXT("ONE"), TEXT("TWO"), TEXT("THREE") };`

Comment: Thanks, Remy. I was struggling to remember the `TEXT` macro.

Comment: I am recycling code that is why range for is not used in this application.

Comment: @Chris So Don't forget to [mark the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) which useful to you.

Answer (score 3):

The `vector` code you have shown does not sort anything.  Strings are added to the ListBox is the same order they appear in the `vector`.

You need to make sure the ListBox itself is being created *without* the [`LBS_SORT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/list-box-styles) window style, which is included by the `LBS_STANDARD` style:

> LBS_SORT
>
> **Sorts strings in the list box alphabetically.**
>
> LBS_STANDARD
>
> **Sorts strings in the list box alphabetically.** The parent window receives a notification code whenever the user clicks a list box item, double-clicks an item, or or cancels the selection. The list box has a vertical scroll bar, and it has borders on all sides. **This style combines the `LBS_NOTIFY`, `LBS_SORT`, `WS_VSCROLL`, and `WS_BORDER` styles**.

Change your `CreateWindow` call to this instead:

```
  hwndList = CreateWindow(
            TEXT("listbox"), 
            NULL,
            WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | /*LBS_STANDARD*/(LBS_NOTIFY | /*LBS_SORT |*/ WS_VSCROLL | WS_BORDER),
            cxChar * COL_LIST, 
            cyChar,
            cxChar * 16 + GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXVSCROLL),
            cyChar * 3,
            hwnd, 
            (HMENU)ID_LIST,
            (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_HINSTANCE),
            NULL);
```

Comment: I am unable to find the LBS_SORT within my project(Visual Studio 2019).  Where is it?

Comment: Where exactly are you creating the ListBox itself?  Are you doing it in code (via `CreateWindow/Ex()`) or via a dialog resource?  You can also remove the style dynamically at runtime via `(Get|Set)WindowLongPtr(GWL_STYLE)` on the ListBox's `HWND`.

Comment: I use the code to create the listbox.  See the listbox code within detail.

Comment: `LBS_SORT` is included in `LBS_STANDARD`. I have updated my answer.

Comment: When removing `LBS_STANDARD`, you then have to explicitly include the other styles that `LBS_STANDARD` would have included for you, other than `LBS_SORT`.  See my updated answer.

Comment: WORKing.  I could probably create any software with stackoverflow as a resource.